# How to remove relationship in Java

Tags: java

I am practising my Java and encountered a problem. I want to make my setPartner method dynamic in the way that in a scenario where p1 and p2 are connected as partners, if I decide to call setPartner() on p1 and p3, p2 gets disconnected. How can I achieve this?

```
public class Partner {

    private final String name;
    private Partner partner;
    private Partner unlinked;

    public Partner(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        partner = null;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Partner getPartner(){
        if (partner != null){
            return partner;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void setPartner(Partner p1, Partner p2){
        if(p1 == null || p2 == null){
            p1.partner = null;
            p2.partner = null;
        }
        else{
            p1.partner = p2;
            p2.partner = p1;
            System.out.println(unlinked);
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Partner p1 = new Partner("JohnP1");     // Create Partner Objects
        Partner p2 = new Partner("JaneP2");
        Partner p3 = new Partner("JacksonP3");

     //   System.out.println(p1.getName());           // Test names
     //   System.out.println(p2.getName());

        p1.setPartner(p1,p2);                       // set partners and test if relation works
        p1.setPartner(p1,p3);

        System.out.println(p2.getPartner().getName());

        //p1.setPartner(p1, null);                    // test for null
        //System.out.println(p2.getPartner().getName());



    }
}
```

Comment: In `setPartner` you check if either is null, and then set both parnters to null - did you mean if either isn't null?

Comment: basically if p3 is not null, p2 is null

Comment: No, If one of the is null, there is no "partnership" to be made, i.e - both are set to null if one is null.

Comment: Your check in `getPartner()` is redundant and the whole method body can be replaced with `return partner;`.

Comment: It also doesn't make sense that `setPartner` takes two parameters. It should operate on `this` and one `Partner` parameter.

Comment: Oftentimes, when you run into troubles like this, the code is trying to tell you something. More often than not, the code is telling you that you are missing an abstraction, in this case a `Relationship` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
public class Partner {
    private final String name;
    private Partner partner;

    public Partner(String name) {
        if (name == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Partner getPartner() {
        return partner;
    }

    public void setPartner(Partner p) {
        // this is critical, or else we'll call each other forever in a loop
        if (partner == p) {
            // we're already partners with p; nothing to do
            return;
        }

        if (partner != null) {
            // already have a partner; tell them we're leaving, directly
            partner.partner = null;  // (we don't want them to call us back)
        }
        partner = p;
        if (p != null) {
            // new partner; let them know about us
            p.setPartner(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Initially it is created with no partner. There's no point I can see to the `unlinked` field or the test you have in `getPartner`. All the work is done in `setPartner`; see the comments there for details.

**Update:**

When we set our partner's partner to `null` to tell them we're leaving, we must do it directly, not by calling their set method, otherwise they'll call us right back to tell them *they're* leaving *us*. Any relation to human relationships is purely coincidental, I'm sure. An earlier version of this answer had a serious bug.

Comment: This is a great solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you connect two partners, they are connected both ways. For example, if you connect P1+P3, then P1.partner == P3 and P3.partner == P1. Now, if you connect P1+P2, then P1.partner == P2 and P2.partner == P1 but P3.partner == P1 from previous connection, so you have to set P3.partner to null. In order to set P3.partner to null, P1.partner.partner = null will do the trick.

```
public void setPartner(Partner p1, Partner p2){
    if(p1 != null && p2 != null){
        if(p1.partner !=null) p1.partner.partner = null;
        if(p2.partner !=null) p2.partner.partner = null;
        p1.partner = p2;
        p2.partner = p1;
        System.out.println(unlinked);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the sort of solution I was looking for, I had totally forgotten the possibility of accessing a partners partner like that! (Even if not extremely optimal).